# Is there a way to configure tls auth for each user for NATS using HELM

Tags: kubernetes-helm, nats.io

I want to configure tls [NATS auth](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/securing_nats/auth_intro/tls_mutual_auth) using HELM, where each user has different certs. Is there a template with K8s to achieve this?